# Bayes Estimator for Bernoulli Variance

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, posterior

I have the following question:

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be independent, identically distributed random variables with
$$
P(X_i=1)=\theta = 1-P(X_i=0)
$$

where $\theta$ is an unknown parameter, $0<\theta<1$, and $n\geq 2$. It is desired to estimate the quantity $\phi = \theta(1-\theta) = nVar((X_1+\dots+X_N)/n)$.

Suppose that a Bayesian approach is adopted and that the prior distribution for $\theta$, $\pi(\theta)$, is taken to be the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. Compute the Bayes point estimate of $\phi$ when the loss function is $L(\phi,a)=(\phi-a)^2$.

Now, my solution so far:

It can easily be proven that $a$ needs to be the mean of the posterior. Also, when $\theta$ spans $(0,1)$, $\phi$ spans $(0,\frac{1}{4}]$. Hence, we have that
$$
a = \int_0^{\frac{1}{4}}\phi\cdot f(\phi|x_1,\dots,x_n)d\phi.
$$

Now, we have that
$$
f(\phi|x_1,\dots,x_n)\propto f(x_1,\dots,x_n|\phi)\cdot \pi(\phi).
$$

Given that $\theta$ follows $U[0,1]$, we get that $\phi$ follows:

$$
P(\Phi\leq t) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4t}}{2}
$$

Hence we can derive $\pi(\phi)$. However, I am not sure how to derive $f(x_i|\phi)$.

Help proceeding forward and letting me know if I have made any mistakes so far would be very appreciated.

Comment: In fact there is no need for the estimator to be the posterior mean. It all depends on the loss function adopted for ranking estimators.

Comment: Yes, it is the mean in the case of this particular loss function. That is why I said it is the mean (in the context of this problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
  \theta \sim \text{Beta}(a_0,b_0)
$$
$$
  X_i\mid\theta\sim\text{Ber}(\theta) \qquad\qquad i=1,\dots,n
$$
$$
  X:=X_1+\dots+X_n
$$
$$
  X\mid\theta \sim \text{Bin}(n,\theta)
$$
$$
  \theta \mid X = x \sim \text{Beta}(x + a_0,n - x + b_0)
$$
$$
  \text{E}[\theta \mid X = x] = \frac{x + a_0}{n + a_0 + b_0}
$$
$$
  \text{Var}[\theta \mid X = x] = \frac{(x+a_0)(n-x+b_0)}{(n + a_0 + b_0)^2(n + a_0 + b_0 + 1)}
$$

$$
  \phi=\text{Var}[X_i \mid \theta]=\theta(1-\theta)
$$

Under quadratic loss, the Bayes estimate for $\phi$ is:
\begin{align*}
  \hat{\phi}_{\text{Bayes}}(x) &= \text{E}[\phi \mid X = x] \\ &= \text{E}[\theta \mid X = x] - \text{E}[\theta^2 \mid X = x] \\
  &= \text{E}[\theta \mid X = x] - \text{Var}[\theta \mid X = x] - \text{E}^2[\theta \mid X = x] \\
&= \frac{(x+a_0)(n-x+b_0)}{(n + a_0 + b_0)(n + a_0 + b_0 + 1)}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to perform the simulation since you do the Bayesian. The posterior for $\theta$ is of closed-form and hence you can easily simulate from $p(\theta|x)$. Then you just apply your function $\phi^m = f(\theta^m) = \theta^m(1 - \theta^m), m = 1,\ldots, N$ where $N$ - number of simulated points from the posterior. Finally you just find $\hat{\phi} = \frac{\sum_{m=1}^N \phi^m}{N}$.

Let me clarify a little bit more. The posterior density for $p(\theta|x)$ has the following form

\begin{align}
p(\theta|x) \sim \mathcal{B}(\alpha + \sum x_i, \beta + n - \sum x_i),
\end{align}
where $\pi(\theta) \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1) = \mathcal{B}(1,1)$, hence $\alpha = \beta = 1$ and $\mathcal{B}(.,.)$ means a beta distribution. Please refer to wiki for the clarifications https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior.  Now you can simulate from this density. See the attached code.

````
# Set a seed
set.seed(3)

# Number of observations
N <- 1e2

# Set the true value to check
theta_true <- 0.5

# Compute the true phi
phi_true <- theta_true*(1 - theta_true)

# Simulate the data given the parameteres
x <- rbinom(N, size = 1, prob = theta_true)

# Estimate the posterior
alpha_new <- 1 + sum(x)
beta_new  <- 1 + N - sum(x)

# Sample from the posterior
theta_sample <- rbeta(n = N, shape1 = alpha_new, shape2 = beta_new)

# Estimate the posterior mean for the draws
mean(theta_sample)
theta_true
# close
phi_sample <- theta_sample*(1 - theta_sample)


# Estimate the posterior mean for the draws
mean(phi_sample)
phi_true
# close
```
````

Comment: I don't get what you mean. I am not supposed to produce a computer simulation. I am interested in the actual mathematical proof of deriving $f(x_i|\phi)$.

Comment: As far as I understand your goal is to compute the $a$, where $a = \mathbb{E}[\phi]$. You can proceed in two ways, the first one is analytically derive the density $f(\phi|x)$ and compute the integral. What I propose is the numerically approximate this number. My suggestion is to sample from the **posterior** $p(\theta|x)$ since this is a well known distribution and then apply the function $\phi = f(\theta) = \theta(1 - \theta)$ to these draws to obtain the posterior draws from the $p(\phi|x)$. Finally, you just average them and obtain the $a$. I will add the R-code.

Answer (score 0):

Since X is a bernoulli random variable, we can say that $f(x_i|\theta)= \theta^{X_i}(1-\theta)^{1- X_i}$, but given is $\phi$, so by equation $\phi = \theta(1-\theta)$, write $\theta = f(\phi)$ and substitute in above equation, we get $$f(x_i|\phi)= f(\phi)^{X_i}(1-f(\phi))^{1- X_i}$$